# Would my sale of chometz affect others?

Tags: transactions, mistakes, chametz-leaven

If one person made a mistake or abused the chometz sale system by selling something that he does not own, would that affect the overall sale between the Rabbi of the community and the non-Jew?

For example if I indicated the wrong address on my document of sale, when my agent, the community Rabbi, goes to sell all the communal chometz does the fact that my document, which is in error, in any way invalidate the total overall sale?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that it would affect yours. Do you have any basis for that?

Comment: @SethJ Maybe he meant: "Would that _effect_ the overall sale?" :) though I don't know what kind of kinyan it could be.

Comment: @SethJ Maybe the example of address doesn't affect it, but we can imagine scenarios where some mistake could effect it.

Comment: @SethJ Ben Ish Hai year 1, Yalkut Yosef 448:9, 448:13 and 448:14 all say that it would drastically affect(and quite possibly nullify) his own sale.  
Whether that would affect the sale of others, would depend on how the Rav actually performed the sale.  Whether he sold it as a lot, or acted as an individual agent for each individual.

Comment: I remember seeing in Piskei Tshuvos that one is allowed to lechatchila sell another person's chametz